# strict comparison fails laravel blade, Some silly mistake by me

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to do a strict comparison regading "male" "female" in radio-box. I know I am certainly doing some silly mistake, but have gone blind regarding.
I have below code where i need checked="ckecked" in radiobox.

```
<p>
    <label for="gender">Gender</label><br>
    <label for="mail">Male</label>
    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" {{ ($a['gender'] ?? '' === "male")? "checked" : "" }} value="male"/>
    @php
      if ($a['gender'] ?? '' === 'female') {
        echo "true";
      }
      else {
        echo "false";
      }
    @endphp
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" {{ ($a['gender'] ?? '' === "female")? "checked" : "" }} value="female"/>
  </p>
```

Whatever may be it this always ckecks the "female" radiobox.
Even

```
@php
      if ($a['gender'] ?? '' === 'female') {
        echo "true";
      }
      else {
        echo "false";
      }
    @endphp
```

Always returns true.
Help needed. Thanks in advance

Amod Karmarkar

Comment: Can you try to force set the variable like, ```@php $a["gender"] = 'male'; @endphp```?

Comment: @KurtFriars. since I use the same form for create and update I am unable to force set the variable. laravel blade gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't worry this is very easy,
you can do it with ignoring else case by use

```
{{isset($a['gender']) && $a['gender'] !="male"?:"checked" }}
```

to checked if current gender is Male

```
{{isset($a['gender']) && $a['gender'] !="female"?:"checked"}}
```

to checked if current gender is Female

Comment: I agree this worked but can anyone explain why === did not do a strict comparison??

Comment: just Accustomed but no problem for this, you can do it and will work

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a strict comparison

```
$a["gender"] = "female"; //assuming that was the array value
echo ($a['gender'] === "female")? "true" : "false"; //this returns true
echo ($a['gender']=== "male")? "true" : "false"; //this returns false
```